# In Directx with UWP, can win32 be used?

Tags: uwp, directx

When programming with DirectX, is using non-UWP practices and keeping things like WinMain and WinProc possible?  I have an older book on win32 for Directx, but it is completely different than UWP.

Comment: UWP uses the `WinMain` entry point, just like any Windows Desktop application. And since DirectX is a decade older than UWP, you certainly can write Windows Desktop applications with DirectX. Why would you assume otherwise? Anyway, it's hard to tell, what you are really after here.

Comment: I read WinMain and WinProc were gone in UWP.  Edit:. I trying to see if it is a waste of time to learn win32, for new projects.

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of magic you attribute to the user-provided entry point. It's just a symbol, and it could be anything. As it happens, UWP's entry point is still the same as for any Win32 application, but depending on the language projection, you may not see it as that. Is it a waste to learn the Windows API? I'd say: No, never. UWP is Win32, just with padded in lots of COM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectX 11 is supported by the Universal Windows Platform (UWP), and the core API is the same as it is in classic Win32 desktop apps. The big differences are in the utility libraries because you can't use the deprecated `D3DX` library in a UWP, and the use of `CoreWindow` instead of Win32 messages and `WndProc`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)
[Where is the DirectX SDK (2015 Edition)?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/)
[Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/)

> You should take a look at [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/) on DirectX book recommendations, as well as the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

*If your book is old enough to be talking about Direct3D 9 or Direct3D 10, then it's not useful for UWP.*

The 'main application' entry-point and loop are different in UWP when using the [C++/CX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699871.aspx) language extensions or using the [C++/WinRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2017/02/11/directx-tool-kit-and-cwinrt/) language projections. That said, you can easily isolate this and just focus on a DirectX swapchain and rendering which is these same in both Win32 classic desktop and UWP apps. I do this in my [Direct3D VS Game templates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/12/17/direct3d-game-visual-studio-templates-redux/) which are structured the same for both platforms.

For C++/CX UWP apps, the entry-point is:

```
ref class ViewProvider sealed : public IFrameworkView
{
    /* There is no WndProc. This class registers for events instead. */
}

ref class ViewProviderFactory : IFrameworkViewSource
{
public:
   virtual IFrameworkView^ CreateView()
   {
       return ref new ViewProvider();
   }
};

[Platform::MTAThread]
int __cdecl main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ argv)
{
    auto viewProviderFactory = ref new ViewProviderFactory();
    CoreApplication::Run(viewProviderFactory);
    return 0;
}
```

For C++/WinRT UWP apps, the entry-point is:

```
class ViewProvider final :
    public winrt::implements<ViewProvider, IFrameworkView>
{
    /* There is no WndProc. This class registers for events instead. */
}

class ViewProviderFactory final : public
     winrt::implements<ViewProviderFactory, IFrameworkViewSource>
{
public:
    IFrameworkView CreateView()
    {
        return winrt::make<ViewProvider>();
    }
};

int WINAPI wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    ViewProviderFactory viewProviderFactory;
    CoreApplication::Run(viewProviderFactory);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That will teach me to buy a $2.02 book at Goodwill.  I forgot about UWP when I bought it, but then it was too latel  All Sales Final at the thrift store.  It's a good cause.